Why do all Python dataclasses always give me a false-positive 'unexpected argument' warning when instantiating them in PyCharm?

For some reason, I'm entirely incapable of making a dataclass and not having PyCharm call it an 'unexpected argument', even though what's shown is valid and, in fact, entirely necessary in order to use dataclasses at all.
I have the latest version of PyCharm, and I have Pydantic installed- it's the same with or without Pydantic. I get the warning regardless of how the class is set up- whether there are type-hints, whether there is a default value or not, it's all irrelevant, it still says 'unexpected argument' for every single variable- like it doesn't understand dataclasses can accept arguments without a user-defined 'init' method.
I restarted PyCharm many times, I invalidated all my caches and did all the built-in trouble-shooting, I updated to the latest version of PyCharm, and I installed the latest version of Pydantic, both through the marketplace, and then manually through a .zip file on my desktop. It remains the same nonetheless.
Why is this happening? And most importantly, how can I fix it?

I've never seen this behavior before. Are you sure you're importing the correct dataclass decorator?

@Carcigenicate I'm using "from dataclasses import dataclass".

@Carcigenicate I think it might be because (for whatever reason) I always get a false-positive 'unexpected argument' when creating a dataclass, if (and only if) the dataclass (i.e, 'from dataclasses import dataclass') is not imported DIRECTLY in the module where said dataclass is DEFINED, so if I pull it from a different module to define a new dataclass, this happens for all instances of said dataclass. I don't know why that is the case...

Ok, I can reproduce that, but why aren't you importing dataclass in the files where it's needed?

Where is the from dataclasses import dataclass? If it's not in the module that defines the dataclass, it won't be defined in that module's namespace.

@Carcigenicate I like having one big 'utilities' module which contains simple utility functions for the program I'm making, and I also usually put most of the imports I'll use in almost every module there (i.e, PyGame) so I don't have to repeat it, and I just... know, that I can call those functions if needed.
It just didn't make any sense to me that this would cause an issue, is all. If I imported 'dataclass' into module A, and import module A into module B via '*', then it should just... work? And it does work, at least functionally- it just false-positives the syntax, for some reason.

@Barmar It's imported in another module (call it moduleA), one which I'm importing into the current one (call it moduleB) with '*'. So, moduleA has 'from dataclasses import dataclass' and module B has 'from moduleA import *', which should work, and it does, but it causes PyCharm to false-positive the syntax for some reason

I guess PyCharm doesn't understand the chain of imports. Report it as a bug.
